# i am not able to display running time in single line even after this code

Tags: java

I am not able to display running time in single line even I have this Code.

```
import java.util.Date;

    public class ServerTime {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(;;)
            {
            Date d = new Date();
            System.out.print(d+"\r");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }   

        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're not a code factory, so please, make some effort and provide us with some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can try and help you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
System.out.print(d+"\r");
```

try this:

```
System.out.println(d);
```

**[EDIT]**

and if you want to show the time in the same line:

```
System.out.print("\r" + d);
```

Comment: Then every output chunk will be in a separate line. What was wanted is to putput and to return to the start of the line. (At least – as far as I understand it)

Comment: I think Sahil misused `\r` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @glglgl I edited my answer and covered what you think :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
System.out.print(d+"\r");
```

Use:

```
System.out.print("\r"+d);
```

Comment: Then you get a tab after each output instead of the cursor going back to the start of the line.

Comment: it is still printing it on next line, what I want is to print running digital clock which overrides the output each second... please give some working code